# Why aren't additional EF diagrams saved in source control?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio

In VS2012/VS2013, you can add additional diagrams to your EF model, which is a great way to control large models. However, when you do this, the changes don't show up in the Pending Changes window, and so aren't saved in source control. This means that if I add a new diagram, no-one else on the team can see it.

Is there a way of sharing these extra diagrams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All diagrams are located in the `EntityModel.edmx.diagram` file. You can open this file with a text editor and verify your changes are there. Sometimes people will put this file on ignore to reduce merge conflicts.

Comment: Thanks, that's great. I don't know why they didn't have this file included in the project in the first place!